# cakephp http how to send response back

Tags: xml, api, http, cakephp

```
public function xml_post_test() {

  $response = $http->get('http://localhost/tests/receive_xml', $xml_string);
  debug ($response->body);
}

public function receive_xml() {
  //send to xml_post_test
}
```

I am new in CakePHP. In the receive_xml, the XML string is received. How to send back to the xml_post_test?

Comment: cakephp automatically renders te corresponding view. If you want to have an xml response read this: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#XmlView

Comment: why do not you switch on debug and chck what you get? After you have processed the data you should use the `set` method in your controller to make available the result in the view. And than use the `_serialize` parameter to get an xml output.